# Possible Bug in Reputation Graph in profile view

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-graph

Today I just visited my profile and notice something weird as below,
Reputation graph shows the reputation growth and from the graph,

[image]

it can be understood that the last growing phase is of or after November Month, However, the month November is just started and that growth(where it grows higher than before in the graph) of my reputation is of last month(October)

Is there a particular reason for this or this is a bug?